# How to set default value in schema mongoose?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

Here I have mongoose schema

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const cartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        items: {
            type: [{
                id_item: String,
                cnt: Number
            }],
            default: [],
            required: true
        },
        dateExpires: Date
})

cartSchema.pre('save', async function(next) {
    this.dateExpires = Date.now() +  7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000;
})

const modelCart = mongoose.model('Cart', cartSchema);
module.exports = modelCart;
```

I'm calling this function below in one of the routes to create a model, if I send empty value it should return empty array and date in database, but what it returns me is `undefined`, default value does not trigger. I'm new in Node.js what could be an issue ?

```
exports.createCart = catchAsync(async (req, res, next) => {
   let newCart = await cartModel.create();
   console.log(newCart); //undefined, wanted items: [], date: ...
        res.status(200).json({
            status: "success",
            data: {
                cart: newCart
            }
        })
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure that you are defining that schema corectly?
[Type is a special property in Mongoose schemas.](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/schematypes.html#type-key)

I think that it should look more like this.

```js
const cartSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
        items: {
            type: Array,
            nested: {
              id_item: { type: String },
              cnt: { type: Number }
            }
            default: [],
            required: true
        },
        dateExpires: Date
})
```